# discord error when installing bot in console

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a bot for discord, everything worked well, after some time it gives an error in the console[in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkifC.png)

I think the error is in the token because all the code worked correctly

Deleted and re-downloaded `discord.py`
Updated `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py`
But nothing helped

Tell me what else can be done?
I will attach the code below:

```
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import time
import json

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
TOKEN = 'My token'

>Bot code that worked without errors<

#Connect
token = open('token.txt', 'r').readline()

bot.run(token)
```

I added the token in two versions: through a text file and in code through  `token = ''`

Comment: Hey Nuestr1k, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include the full traceback as a `code block`, not as **an image**.

Answer (score 1):

`intents=discord.Intents.all()`
is a serious statement, are you sure you really need all the intents?
if so, are you sure you enabled all the intents on the discord dev portal? that line may be causing the issue for you, try removing it.

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't know if I agree with having all intents on as "serious", though. Most people do it for simplicity's sake.

Comment: that is because you have to enable it from the dev portal and it confuses a lot of beginners, as they cant really make sense of the huge asyncio tracebacks that come with wrong intents, where the actual message is hidden somewhere in it